# How to set the responsive width of Polymer component inside `<iron-list grid>`

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, css-calc, iron-list

Consider the following code, where `<my-item>` always has a fixed width of `200px` inside `<iron-list grid>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Polymer Element Test Case</title>
  <!-- Load webcomponents-loader.js to check and load any polyfills your browser needs -->
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-list/iron-list.html">
</head>
<body>

  <h1>iron-list-grid-calc-issue</h1>
  <!-- Test case HTML goes here -->

  <test-case>
  </test-case>

  <dom-module id="test-case">
    <template>
      <iron-list items="[[items]]" grid>
        <template>
          <div>
            <!-- value: [[item.n]] -->
            <my-item data="[[item]]"></my-item>
          </div>
        </template>
      </iron-list>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="my-item">

    <template>
      <style>
        .content {
          width: calc(50% - 32px); /* Not working */
          width: 200px;
          height: 200px;
          line-height: 200px;
          text-align: center;
          border: 1px solid grey;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
      </style>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
          data: [[data.n]]
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

  <script>
    window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
      class TestCase extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
          return 'test-case';
        }

        static get properties() {
          return {
            items: {
              type: Array,
              value: function() {
                let items = [];
                for (let i=0; i < 10; i++) {
                  items.push({
                    n: i,
                  });
                }

                return items;
              }
            },
          };
        }
      }

      class MyItem extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
          return 'my-item';
        }

        static get properties() {
          return {
            data: Object,
          };
        }
      }

      window.customElements.define(TestCase.is, TestCase);
      window.customElements.define(MyItem.is, MyItem);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I intend to make `<my-item>` responsive by always showing 2 `<my-item>`s per row (which can be stretched) by setting the width of `<my-item>` with `width: calc(50% - 32px)`. I noticed CSS `calc()` doesn't seem to work as expected.

How do I set the responsive width of a Polymer component inside `<iron-list grid>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the size of the item template's root container element (`<div>` in this case).

```
<iron-list items="[[items]]" grid>
  <template>
    <div style="width: calc(50% - 32px); height: 200px"> <!-- root container element -->
      <my-item data="[[item]]"></my-item>
    </div>
  </template>
</iron-list>
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.3.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-list/iron-list.html">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>iron-list-grid-calc-issue</h1>
  <test-case></test-case>

  <dom-module id="test-case">
    <template>
      <style>
        .item {
          width: calc(50% - 32px);
          height: 200px;
        }
      </style>
      <iron-list items="[[items]]" grid>
        <template>
          <!-- Set the size of the item template's root container,
               which is this `div` element. -->
          <div class="item">
            <my-item data="[[item]]"></my-item>
          </div>
        </template>
      </iron-list>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="my-item">

    <template>
      <style>
        .content {
          /* NOTE: The item size is set in the item template
             in `iron-list` */

          /*width: calc(50% - 32px);*/
          /*width: 200px;*/
          /*height: 200px;*/
          line-height: 200px;
          text-align: center;
          border: 1px solid grey;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
      </style>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
          data: [[data.n]]
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

  <script>
    window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
      class TestCase extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
          return 'test-case';
        }

        static get properties() {
          return {
            items: {
              type: Array,
              value: function() {
                let items = [];
                for (let i=0; i < 10; i++) {
                  items.push({
                    n: i,
                  });
                }

                return items;
              }
            },
          };
        }
      }

      class MyItem extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
          return 'my-item';
        }

        static get properties() {
          return {
            data: Object,
          };
        }
      }

      window.customElements.define(TestCase.is, TestCase);
      window.customElements.define(MyItem.is, MyItem);
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/qpmYJd?editors=1000)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is it possible to set it inside <my-item>, instead of setting it in the <iron-list>?